# How to remove item form array?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following array in my React naitve app.

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { answers: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] },
    { answers: [{ id: 1 }] },
    { answers: [{ id: 1 },] },
  ]);
```

I want to delete item from first row with ***id 2*** So the final should look like that

```
[
    { answers: [{ id: 1 }] },
    { answers: [{ id: 1 }] },
    { answers: [{ id: 1 }] },
  ]
```

How can i do that ?
I tried to start like this

```
  const onDelete = useCallback((itemId) => {
    var newItems = [...items];

    newItems = newItems[0].answers.filter(....) //I don't know how to continue

    setItems(newItems);
  }, []);
```

Sorry for the question but I'm new to react-native and javascript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've expanded @sm3sher answer to allow removing answer ids at any index.

```
const onDelete = useCallback((answerId=2,itemIndex=0)=>{
  const newItems = [...items];
  let currentItem = newItems[itemIndex]
  currentItem.answers = currentItem.answers.filter(({id})=> id !== answerId)
  newItems[itemIndex] = currentItem;
  setItems(newItems);
},[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to change the **first object** and you want do dynamically filter the answers based on your `itemId`, the `onDelete` function would look like this:

```
  const onDelete = useCallback((itemId) => {
    setItems((prev) => [
      { answers: prev[0].answers.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId) },
      ...prev.slice(1),
    ]);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new object, whose `answers` property is the filtered original. The filter callback can be `({id}) => id != 2`:

```
   newItems[0] = { answers: newItems[0].answers.filter(({id}) => id != 2) };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newItems = newItems.map(item => { return item.answers.filter(answer => answer.id !== 2)})
```

Comment: I dont think this would work as it delete all answer keys of the id 2 and alter items to be nothing a list of ids